# emacs orgmode do not insert line between headers?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, line-breaks, heading

In emacs org-mode, when I make a new sub-heading,(org-insert-subheading), sometimes it adds a blank line, sometimes it doesn't based on some pattern in text above.

Can I force emacs to never insert a line break?

I.e,

```
* Heading 1
** Heading 2  #no line breaks.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is controlled by the variable `org-blank-before-new-entry`. As per the Org documentation:

> Should `org-insert-heading` leave a blank line before new heading/item?
>   The value is an alist, with `heading` and `plain-list-item` as CAR,
>   and a boolean flag as CDR.  The cdr may also be the symbol `auto', in
>   which case Org will look at the surrounding headings/items and try to
>   make an intelligent decision whether to insert a blank line or not.
>
> For plain lists, if `org-list-empty-line-terminates-plain-lists` is set,
>   the setting here is ignored and no empty line is inserted to avoid breaking
>   the list structure.

The default value is `'((heading . auto) (plain-list-item . auto))`, so it normally will insert a newline before a heading (the `auto` part in the `heading`). You can specify `Never` when you customize the variable, and it will not insert a newline.

Answer (score 12):

This is controlled by the variable `org-blank-before-new-entry`:

> Should `` `org-insert-heading' `` leave a blank line before new heading/item?
>   The value is an alist, with `` `heading' `` and `` `plain-list-item' `` as CAR, and a boolean flag as CDR. The cdr may also be the symbol `` `auto' ``, in which case Org will look at the surrounding headings/items and try to make an intelligent decision whether to insert a blank line or not.

On my version of emacs, the default for both items is `auto`. To never insert blank lines, set both to `nil`:

```
(setf org-blank-before-new-entry '((heading . nil) (plain-list-item . nil)))
```

Comment: I found this does not work (it seems to interpret `nil` as `auto`), but `(setf org-blank-before-new-entry '((heading . never) (plain-list-item . never)))` does. My version: "GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0)
 of 2021-03-27, modified by Debian"

Comment: Can this approach remove newline in between `TODOs` as well?